# string + replaced by whitespace

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I'm developing an app using Django rest framework while getting `query` object from the `request` the string containing `+` character is replaced by whitespace.

html javascript code:

```
query = 's9+';
$.get("/api/v1/autocomplete?query=" + query, function(data, status){
        str = JSON.stringify(data, null, 4);
        document.getElementById("response").innerHTML = str;
    });
```

Django rest framework code:

```
    def get(self, request):
        search_query = request.GET.get('query', None)
        print("search_query " + search_query)
```

Django code print `s9` instead of `s9+`.

How to prevent Django from auto converting `+` in the string to whitespaces?

Comment: By encoding it. Don't write such querystring yourself.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem how? any example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The elements of a querystring are **encoded**. Indeed for example the `?`, `&` and `=` characters can not be used as well, since those are *separators*.

In case you want to encode content, you better use utility functions like [**`encodeURIComponent`** [doc]](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent):

```
query = 's9+';
$.get("/api/v1/autocomplete?query=" + encodeURIComponent(query), function(data, status){
        str = JSON.stringify(data, null, 4);
        document.getElementById("response").innerHTML = str;
    });
```

It is better to encode all parameters, since several character sets can not be encoded straightforward to a querystring (cyrillic, special characters, diacritics, etc.).